# Split an array according to cluster labels

Tags: python, numpy

I'm supposed to code a function that *Receives a labeled dataset and splits the datapoints according to label*:

```py
def get_clusters(X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> List[np.ndarray]:
    """
    Receives a labeled dataset and splits the datapoints according to label

    Args:
        X (np.ndarray): The dataset
        y (np.ndarray): The label for each point in the dataset

    Returns:
        List[np.ndarray]: A list of arrays where the elements of each array
        are datapoints belonging to the label at that index.

    Example:
    >>> get_clusters(
            np.array([[0.8, 0.7], [0, 0.4], [0.3, 0.1]]),
            np.array([0,1,0])
        )
    >>> [array([[0.8, 0.7],[0.3, 0.1]]),
         array([[0. , 0.4]])]
    """
    idx = np.unique(y,return_index = True)[1]


    C = []
    for i,label in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
    
        if i != len(idx)-1:
            C.append(X[idx[i]:idx[i+1]])
        
        else:
            C.append(X[idx[i]:])
    return C
```

This is what I tried so far, but appearently it only works with a sorted input. I'm not allowed to use more then one for loop. Has anyone an idea how I can improve the function?

I hope I included all necessary information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split an array into a `list` of subarrays with [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html). You assumed correctly that this only works with sorted input. So we have to sort the input first.

```py
def get_clusters(X, y):
    s = np.argsort(y)
    return np.split(X[s], np.unique(y[s], return_index=True)[1][1:])
```

A complete, reproducible test example

```
import numpy as np
from typing import List

def get_clusters(X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> List[np.ndarray]:
    s = np.argsort(y)
    return np.split(X[s], np.unique(y[s], return_index=True)[1][1:])

get_clusters(
        np.array([[0.8, 0.7], [0, 0.4], [0.3, 0.1]]),
        np.array([0,1,0])
)
```

Output

```
[array([[0.8, 0.7],[0.3, 0.1]]),
 array([[0. , 0.4]])]
```

---

### Microbenchmark `np.argsort`/`np.split` vs `np.where`

I benchmarked @CJR's `np.where` solution against `np.split` after sorting with 1/10 unique labels and with decreasing unique labels for a constant array size.

Results for growing array sizes (1/10 unique labels)

[image: results]

Results for decreasing unique labels (10000/10 to 10000/90, the x-axis label is incorrect) constant array size of 10000

[image: results2]

Code used for the benchmark

```
import numpy as np
from typing import List
import perfplot

def get_clusters_sort(X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> List[np.ndarray]:
    s = np.argsort(y)
    return np.split(X[s], np.unique(y[s], return_index=True)[1][1:])

def get_clusters_loop(X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> List[np.ndarray]:    
    return [X[np.where(y == label)[0]] for label in np.unique(y)]

perfplot.show(
    setup = lambda n: (np.random.rand(n,2), np.random.randint(n//10, size=n)),
    kernels = [
        lambda x: get_clusters_sort(*x),
        lambda x: get_clusters_loop(*x)
        ],
    labels = ['sort','loop'],
    n_range = [2**k for k in range(10,19)],
    xlabel = 'len(a)',
    equality_check=False
)
```

Code changes to estimate the influence of `len(unique(labels))`

```
perfplot.show(
    setup = lambda n: (np.random.rand(10000,2), np.random.randint(10000//n, size=10000)),
    kernels = [
        lambda x: get_clusters_sort(*x),
        lambda x: get_clusters_loop(*x)
        ],
    labels = ['sort','loop'],
    n_range = [k for k in range(10,100,10)],
    xlabel = 'len(unique(labels))',
    equality_check=False
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorting seems like a lot of work. Another option is using `np.where` to get indices.

```
import numpy as np

def get_clusters(X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> List[np.ndarray]:
    
    return [X[np.where(y == label)[0], :] for label in np.unique(y)]
```

Gives the same result:

```
get_clusters(
        np.array([[0.8, 0.7], [0, 0.4], [0.3, 0.1]]),
        np.array([0,1,0])
)

[array([[0.8, 0.7],
        [0.3, 0.1]]),
 array([[0. , 0.4]])]
```

Comment: I think your solution is `O(n^2)`-ish, while sorting is `O(n*log(n))`-ish. I added a benchmark to my answer. I don't know how to estimate `len(unique(labels))`. That is a relevant factor for the runtime.

Comment: Yeah that complexity analysis is probably right. I don't think there's any advantage to doing it this way (maybe if you're splitting on a different axis, where np.split is forced into a copy, but probably not even then).